# querying multiple results from MediaWiki / Wikipedia using Android or Java

Tags: java, android, http, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am currently using MediaWiki's URL example to query HTTP GET requests on android.

I am simply getting information through a URL like this;

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content
```

However, in this example, I always need some sort of direct title and only get one result back (titles=some name here)

I know that Wikipedia has more complex search methods explained here;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching

I would like to offer a few "previews" of multiple wikipedia article per search, since what they type might not always be what they want.

Is there any way to query these special "search" results?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [MediaWiki search API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch) may be what you're after. That particular page discusses getting previews of search results.